# Wildfly : Is there any overhead enabling ejbs and datasources statistics?

Tags: statistics, wildfly, overhead

In the wildfly config file (standalone.xml), it is possible to enable statistics for the ejb and datasources susbsystems
I would like to enable them to get useful infos at runtime (invocations, execution times,...)

But is it something that can be activated on a production server ?
Is there any overhead ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both question is yes :) you can activate it and there will be an overhead.
You can use the jboss-cli to enable/disable the stats without requiring a restart of the server.

Comment: Do you know how big this overhead might be ? Are we talking of an overhead of about 1% or 10%?

Comment: i honestly don't know.

Comment: @ehsavoie are you sure you don't need to restart the server? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599261/304270